# UIImageView does not change UIImage

Tags: ios, swift

I have a custom `UIView` which contains `UIImageView`, `UIButton` and I have added a target on `UIButton` to get event. That action target method wants to change `UIImageView` image. For normal it is showing white image and after selection it would change to red image.

The code is changing the image but it is taking 10-15 seconds. Although I have also written in `DispatchQueue.main` but I am getting the same result for any condition.

```swift
@objc func professionSelected(sender: Any?) -> Void {
    let selectedBtn = sender as? UIButton
    print("Button selectd \(selectedBtn?.titleLabel?.text ?? "")")

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.pBackgroundImage?.image = UIImage.init(named: "Rectangle-Red")
        self.setNeedsDisplay()
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
 }
```

Comment: Whats the size and resolution of the image "Rectangle-Red"??. 10-15 seconds is too long. And secondly, if you really need to load that big image, load image in background thread first and set it to `ImageView` in main thread.

Comment: You need to show what else is going on in your code. Changing the `.image` of a `UIImageVIew` on a button tap should be instantaneous (unless you're trying to load a *giant* image), and you don't need dispatch it to the main queue, nor do you need to call `setNeedsDisplay()` or `.layoutIfNeeded()`

Comment: If your image is really big, scale it down. A super high quality isn't necessary for mobile screens, and it will render quicker. Also, is the button immediately responsive?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `DispatchQueue.main.async`. Use like below.

```
@objc func professionSelected(sender: Any?) -> Void {

   let selectedBtn = sender as? UIButton
   print("Button selectd \(selectedBtn?.titleLabel?.text ?? "")")
   self.pBackgroundImage?.image = UIImage(named: "Rectangle-Red")
}
```

Comment: It is updating but taking time.

Comment: Hierarchy is like this UIView->CustomContainerView->CustomButtonView

Comment: what is your image Rectangle-Red type and size ? create a image variable in the starting at viewDidLoad method and just assign this image to pBackgroundImage on button press action

Comment: It is png type image and perfect with the background image. It is updating but after 10-15 seconds delay, seems like some thread is completing an then updating.

Comment: Make sure you separate your long tasks using the `global(qos:)` method from `DispatchQueue`. Otherwise, you will block up the main thread (therefore getting a delay).

Comment: Is your message (`Button selectd ....`) printing is also getting delayed?